# SQL pivoted table is read-only and cells can't be edited?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

If I create a VIEW using this pivot table query, it isn't editable.   The cells are read-only and give me the SQL2005 error:  "No row was updated.  The data in row 2 was not committed.  Update or insert of view or function 'VIEWNAME' failed because it contains a derived or constant field."

Any ideas on how this could be solved OR is a pivot like this just never editable?

```
SELECT     n_id,
MAX(CASE field WHEN 'fId' THEN c_metadata_value ELSE ' ' END) AS fId,
MAX(CASE field WHEN 'sID' THEN c_metadata_value ELSE ' ' END) AS sID,
MAX(CASE field WHEN 'NUMBER' THEN c_metadata_value ELSE ' ' END) AS NUMBER
FROM   metadata
GROUP BY n_id
```

Comment: Do you have a unique constraint on `n_id, field`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create trigger on view, because direct update is not possible:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TrMyViewUpdate on MyView
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   UPDATE MyTable
   SET ...
   FROM INSERTED...
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a unique constraint on `n_id, field` which means that at most one row can match you can (in theory at least) use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger.

This would be easier with `MERGE` (but that is not available until SQL Server 2008) as you need to cover `UPDATES` of existing data, `INSERTS` (Where a `NULL` value is set to a `NON NULL` one) and `DELETES` where a `NON NULL` value is set to `NULL`.

One thing you would need to consider here is how to cope with `UPDATES` that set all of the columns in a row to `NULL` I did this during testing the code below and was quite confused for a minute or two until I realised that this had deleted all the rows in the base table for an `n_id` (which meant the operation was not reversible via another `UPDATE` statement). This issue could be avoided by having the VIEW definition `OUTER JOIN` onto what ever table  `n_id` is the PK of.

An example of the type of thing is below. You would also need to consider potential race conditions in the `INSERT`/`DELETE` code indicated and whether you need some additional locking hints in there.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig
ON pivoted
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
      SET nocount ON;

      DECLARE @unpivoted TABLE (
        n_id             INT,
        field            VARCHAR(10),
        c_metadata_value VARCHAR(10))

      INSERT INTO @unpivoted
      SELECT *
      FROM   inserted UNPIVOT (data FOR col IN (fid, sid, NUMBER) ) AS unpvt
      WHERE  data IS NOT NULL

      UPDATE m
      SET    m.c_metadata_value = u.c_metadata_value
      FROM   metadata m
             JOIN @unpivoted u
               ON u.n_id = m.n_id
                  AND u.c_metadata_value = m.field;

      /*You need to consider race conditions below*/
      DELETE FROM metadata
      WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                        FROM   @unpivoted u
                        WHERE  metadata.n_id = u.n_id
                               AND u.field = metadata.field)

      INSERT INTO metadata
      SELECT u.n_id,
             u.field,
             u.c_metadata_value
      FROM   @unpivoted u
      WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                         FROM   metadata m
                         WHERE  m.n_id = u.n_id
                                AND u.field = m.field)
  END
```

Comment: If you have update and insert, there should also be a delete, right?