# Is it possible to create an editable view of a many-to-manyrelashionship?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2008-r2

Consider the following tables:

**Products**

```
ID | Name | etc
1  | Pen  | wtv
2  | Pad  | wtv
3  | Ball | wtv
...| ...  | ...
thousands of products
```

**Categories**

```
ID | Name   | etc
1  | Office | wtv
2  | Home   | wtv
3  | Park   | wtv
...| ...    | ...
hundreds of categories
```

**productCategoryMatrix**

```
ProductID | CategoryID
1         | 1
1         | 2
2         | 1
2         | 2
2         | 3
3         | 3
... et cetera
```

The matrix allows assigning multiple categories to a single product (the typical many-to-many relashionship). For example, the *Pen* belongs to two categories, *Office*, and *Home*. I wish to create **an editable view** of this data which would look like this:

**ProductsWithCategories**

```
ProductID | ProductName | Category | Category | Category | Category | Category
1         | Pen         | 1        | 2        |          |          |
2         | Pad         | 1        | 2        | 3        |          |
3         | Ball        | 3        |          |          |          |
          |               ... Thousands of products ...             |
```

Note that if a product is assigned less than 5 categories, the last columns may remain empty, as in the example. Also note that business logic dictates that there will never be more than 5 categories assigned to a single product, and therefore only five columns are necessary.

Is it possible to create this kind of view with SQL Server 2008 R2?
If your solutions also work with SQL Server 2000, that would be awesome as we only upgrade to 2008 in three weeks. If not, no matter, we will wait :)

Answer (score 2):

Any view can be made updatable using an INSTEAD OF trigger.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

In your case, there is no way for SQL Server to automatically make it updatable, but you can map columns to rows in your trigger.

Have a look at these pages:

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=120679

[SQL pivoted table is read-only and cells can't be edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011944/sql-pivoted-table-is-read-only-and-cells-cant-be-edited/5012058#5012058)

A view can be made from this:

```
DECLARE @Products TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(50));
DECLARE @Categories AS TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(50));
DECLARE @ProductCategoryMatrix AS TABLE (ProductID INT, CategoryID INT);

INSERT INTO @Products (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'Pen'), (2, 'Pad'), (3, 'Ball');
INSERT INTO @Categories VALUES (1, 'Office'), (2, 'Home'), (3, 'Work');
INSERT INTO @ProductCategoryMatrix VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3);

-- CREATE VIEW AS -- (change variables to real tables)
WITH CategoriesOrdered AS (
    SELECT p.ID AS ProductID
           ,'Cat' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pc.ProductID ORDER BY pc.CategoryID) AS VARCHAR(1)) AS CategoryColumn
           ,pc.CategoryID
    FROM @Products p
    INNER JOIN @ProductCategoryMatrix pc
        ON pc.ProductID = p.ID
)
,CategoriesFlat AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM CategoriesOrdered
    PIVOT (MIN(CategoryID) FOR CategoryColumn IN ([Cat1], [Cat2], [Cat3], [Cat4], [Cat5])) AS pvt
)
,ProductsWithCategories AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM @Products p
    LEFT JOIN CategoriesFlat cf
        ON cf.ProductID = p.ID
)
SELECT *
FROM ProductsWithCategories;
```

Making a trigger on this would involve quite a bit of code, but not terribly difficult.

Comment: Could you give a quick example of this kind of procedure?

Comment: @Shawn see the two links I give.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Unfortunately, they don't accomplish what I'm trying to do. Their method creates a new column for every category (of which I have hundreds), similarily to Indikaf's solution. I want only 5 columns in which category IDs will appear... The ProductsWithCategories table in my question illustrates what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Shawn See live example at http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/64201/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-9709235

Comment: @Shawn note that the ROW_NUMBER and PIVOT require SQL Server 2005 and up, but there are ways of doing the same thing in SQL Server 2000, but just more verbose - the theory of the pivot and rank are still the same.

Answer (score 0):

this works perfectly on sql 2k, i have tested

```
select 
p.ID, 
p.Name,
c1.cid     as cat1,
c2.cid     as cat2,
c3.cid     as cat3,
c4.cid     as cat4,
c5.cid     as cat5
from 
Products p
inner join                    --  use left join if you want to have listed products with any category
   (select pcm1.ProductID, min(pcm1.CategoryID) as cid
    from productCategoryMatrix pcm1 group by ProductID) as c1 on p.ID = c1.productID

left join
   (select pcm1.productID, min(pcm2.CategoryID) as cid
    from      productCategoryMatrix pcm1
    left join productCategoryMatrix pcm2 on pcm1.productID = pcm2.productID and pcm1.CategoryID < pcm2.CategoryID
    group by pcm1.ProductID
   ) as c2 on p.ID = c2.productID

left join
   (select pcm1.productID, min(pcm3.CategoryID) as cid
    from      productCategoryMatrix pcm1
    left join productCategoryMatrix pcm2 on pcm1.productID = pcm2.productID and pcm1.CategoryID < pcm2.CategoryID
    left join productCategoryMatrix pcm3 on pcm1.productID = pcm3.productID and pcm2.CategoryID < pcm3.CategoryID
    group by pcm1.ProductID
   ) as c3 on p.ID = c3.productID

left join
   (select pcm1.productID, min(pcm4.CategoryID) as cid
    from      productCategoryMatrix pcm1
    left join productCategoryMatrix pcm2 on pcm1.productID = pcm2.productID and pcm1.CategoryID < pcm2.CategoryID
    left join productCategoryMatrix pcm3 on pcm1.productID = pcm3.productID and pcm2.CategoryID < pcm3.CategoryID
    left join productCategoryMatrix pcm4 on pcm1.productID = pcm4.productID and pcm3.CategoryID < pcm4.CategoryID
    group by pcm1.ProductID
   ) as c4 on p.ID = c4.productID

left join
   (select pcm1.productID, min(pcm5.CategoryID) as cid
    from      productCategoryMatrix pcm1
    left join productCategoryMatrix pcm2 on pcm1.productID = pcm2.productID and pcm1.CategoryID < pcm2.CategoryID
    left join productCategoryMatrix pcm3 on pcm1.productID = pcm3.productID and pcm2.CategoryID < pcm3.CategoryID
    left join productCategoryMatrix pcm4 on pcm1.productID = pcm4.productID and pcm3.CategoryID < pcm4.CategoryID
    left join productCategoryMatrix pcm5 on pcm1.productID = pcm5.productID and pcm4.CategoryID < pcm5.CategoryID
    group by pcm1.ProductID
   ) as c5 on p.ID = c5.productID
```

Comment: @Shawn what about this solution, have you tested? it is not what you want?